# Is it right for Amateur Radio operators to hide their antennas?

Tags: antenna

1. **Is it right for us hams to hide our antennas?**
2. **And should we tell our neighbors that we are a ham?**

Comment: Yeah, this is a poorly-worded question. Is it right? Well, that’s an opinion.

Comment: Sorry @ScottEarle! It seemed like a good idea at the time! ;-)

Comment: Point #2 does not match the title of the question.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Yes it is.**
2. **No, it's usually a bad idea.**

[image: Any questions?]

### Any Questions?

This was prompted by [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7615/shortwave-cb-ham).

Lots of law-abiding hams need to hide their antennas. HOA rules, objections from spouse and neighbors. Ask most any city ham: they will tell you that the mere presence of their antenna even if not connected is the "cause" of their neighbor's problems with their TV, radio, garbage disposal, sickness ... the list is infinite.

Comment: A moderator just pointed out that this question is opinion-based (against the SE rules). How can this be fixed so it's not? [**Please answer here**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11162/ham-shack).

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is if you live in a development (Condos come to mind) with restrictive CC&Rs banning visible antennas.  In that case, there is no opinion about it.  In order to operate, the antenna must be hidden.  Part 2 is a matter of personal preference, on the order of deciding whether to tell a neighbor whether or not you own goldfish.   I suppose there could be many opinions on that.  So, the entire question is not primarily opinion-based.  To fix the question, I'd say to separate this into two questions.  (I remember this comic from when it came out)